# Android Annotations: Query params gets appended to url?

Tags: android, android-annotations

```
@Get("/ServiceTest?version=1&dateRange={dateRange}")
ResponseModel getDateRangeTest(String dateRange);
```

in RestClient interface this make the following Get

```
http://localhost:8080/ServiceTest/2014-01-29%25202014-01-29?version=1" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
```

Am i doing something wrong in sending the query params.

I want address this way:

```
/ServiceTest?version=1&dataRange=2014-01-29%25202014-01-29
```

Which in this case somehow i am failed to generate with Android annotations @Get

**Answer**: My calls were not correct and main problem was with uri encode, correct one is

```
/ServiceTest?version=1&dataRange=2014-01-29%202014-01-29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might do wrong.

Your server get `/ServiceTest`
but you access server with address `/ServiceTest/2014-01-29%25202014-01-29`

Look careful that your server receive as **/ServiceTest?version=1&dateRange=**{dateRange}
and {dataRange} is what you intend to give as variable.

Your address should be `/ServiceTest?version=1&dataRange=2014-01-29%25202014-01-29`

**== EDIT ==**

I'm not familiar with Android Get annotation, but try this.

```
@Get("/ServiceTest?version=1&dateStart={dateStart}&dateEnd={dateEnd}")
ResponseModel getDateRangeTest(String dateStart, String dateEnd);
```

and access with `/ServiceTest?version=1&dataStart=2014-01-29&dateEnd=2014-01-29`

Note that I change argument for more specific. and it would be a better approach.

Comment: @NavdeepSingh // look again. I added.

Comment: This is not the case. Android-Annotation is the culprit.

Comment: @NavdeepSingh // Did you try with `/ServiceTest?version=1&dataRange=2014-01-29%202014-01-29` ? See `%2520` and `%20` differences in the address.

Comment: yes this encoded URI, when i send blank space should be converted to %20 but here i can see %2520

Comment: @NavdeepSingh // you might check http://stackoverflow.com/q/16084935/361100 link. and why don't you manually replace %2520 to %20?

Comment: Thanks for this case, this is one another problem, Android annotations automatically encodes the string ... but still the main problem persists.

Comment: @NavdeepSingh // glad to hear that :)