# angular encode space as + not %20

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I am using angular 1.4.8 and there is bug i thing with encode parameter in get request.

This is my service :

```
   angular
        .module('test')
        .factory('User',User);

    /* @ngInject */
    function User($resource) {
        return $resource('api/users/:login', {}, {
            'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            },
            'save': {method: 'POST'},
            'update': {method: 'PUT'},
            'delete': {method: 'DELETE'}
        });
    }
```

and this when i use it:

```
     return User.get({
                        page: 1,
                        size: 20,
                        sort: 'email asc'  //THIS IS A PROBLEM
                    }
                    ).$promise.then(function (data, headersGetter) {

                       return data.content;
                    });
```

My request is :

```
http://localhost:3000/api/users?page=0&size=10&sort=email+asc
```

But its should look like :

```
http://localhost:3000/api/users?page=0&size=10&sort=email%20asc
```

Why angular not properly encode that parameter ??
How to fix this issue ?

Comment: GET parameters are not designed to work with spaces. I would use two fields: sortField and sortType

Comment: Try adding `transformRequest: []` to the 'get' definition. This should make sure no unwanted transformations are happening to the request.

Comment: can't you just decode the param at server?

Comment: I dont manage server so i can't change implementation

Comment: @jim0thy i add as yout say  : ```'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformRequest: [],
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            },``` its still not working i have got + sign

Answer (score 1):

You can manually encode if needed. 
Try this:

```
sort: encodeURIComponent('email asc')
```

Or better yet, wrap the entire finished url string in encodeURIComponent.

Note that spaces in url parameters are not valid. Encoding will add %2520 where the space was.

[See this question asking/explaining reason for %2520 instead of %20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084935/a-html-space-is-showing-as-2520-instead-of-20)

[See this other question and the answer quoting the RFC.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space)

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't encode by default? It does internally

Comment: When i do this as you say i have got : 
```http://localhost:3000/api/users?page=0&size=10&sort=email%2520asc```

Comment: @charlietfl - can you elaborate? I do not see any encoding taking place in my app unless I manually specify it.

Comment: GET params are encoded when they are serialized. Look in angular source  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L26

Comment: @charlietfl - you're definitely right, and yet in my app I do not see encoding on many characters. Not sure why. I will change my answer.