# Issue getting URL from String for use with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, url, avplayer, nsurl

I have constructed a string that is the directory path and file name of file i would like to play in AVPlayer.  But I'm struggling to convert this to a URL.

```
let dataPath = ("\(packDirectory)/").appending((cachedFilePath as NSString).lastPathComponent)
print(dataPath)
audioFileURL = dataPath
self.audioPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: NSURL.fileURL(withPath: audioFileURL) as URL)
print(self.audioPlayerItem)
```

print(dataPath) returns:

```
/Users/Geoff/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A31BF8F8-21F6-4227-97B6-9DBDED26CA3E/data/Containers/Data/Application/788085B9-242E-46E7-9644-6A3BF9D515DB/Documents/Next-pk000/7b54d8a0f1a64b710058d4408ca4d696_The%20Name%20of%20the%20Wind%2029-92.mp3
```

print(self.audioPlayerItem) returns: - the url part:

```
URL = file:///Users/Geoff/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A31BF8F8-21F6-4227-97B6-9DBDED26CA3E/data/Containers/Data/Application/788085B9-242E-46E7-9644-6A3BF9D515DB/Documents/Next-pk000/7b54d8a0f1a64b710058d4408ca4d696_The%2520Name%2520of%2520the%2520Wind%252029-92.mp3
```

I don't really understand this stuff but i can see 2 issues with this.

1) file://  : i have purposely removed this from my "dataPath" as when using file manager it cant find anything with this prefix.  i have used this code for that:

```
userDirectory.removeSubrange(userDirectory.startIndex..<userDirectory.index(userDirectory.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
let packDirectory = userDirectory.appending("Next-\(self.selectedPack!)")
```

2) the encoding in the .lastComponent has been changed from %20 to %2520

Very confused !

---- EDIT ----

```
let urlItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioFileURL))
if let urlAsset = urlItem.asset as? AVURLAsset {
    self.audioPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: NSURL(string: urlAsset.url.path) as! URL)
    print(urlAsset.url.path)
}
print(self.audioPlayerItem!)
```

print(urlAsset.url.path) returns :

```
/Users/Geoff/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A31BF8F8-21F6-4227-97B6-9DBDED26CA3E/data/Containers/Data/Application/BAD0194A-8CDD-44CE-BF99-B9FF35E23BCA/Documents/Next-pk000/7b54d8a0f1a64b710058d4408ca4d696_The%20Name%20of%20the%20Wind%2029-92.mp3
```

print(self.audioPlayerItem!) returns:

```
<AVPlayerItem: 0x7bf81b60, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x7bf87c70, URL = /Users/Geoff/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A31BF8F8-21F6-4227-97B6-9DBDED26CA3E/data/Containers/Data/Applicati ... 9-92.mp3>>

self.audioPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlAsset.url.path))
```

prints:

```
file:///Users/Geoff/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A31BF8F8-21F6-4227-97B6-9DBDED26CA3E/data/Containers/Data/Application/7C212656-8E1C-44C8-9951-4444FB5EF853/Documents/Next-pk000/7b54d8a0f1a64b710058d4408ca4d696_The%2520Name%2520of%2520the%2520Wind%252029-92.mp3
```

even using something like:

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: urlAsset.url.path)!) as AVAsset
```

results in losing some of the url:

```
<AVPlayerItem: 0x79716ed0, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x797185d0, URL = /Users/Geoff/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A31BF8F8-21F6-4227-97B6-9DBDED26CA3E/data/Containers/Data/Applicati ... 9-92.mp3>>
```

And nothing plays.  So basically i think it won't play with the file:// prefix but when i plug in the string without it something cuts the path at the i in applications???

Comment: Please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can read about `absoluteString` and `path` of [URL documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url).
   For getting `self.audioPlayerItem's URL` with lacking of `file:///` you can access asset of `self.audioPlayerItem` and get path of `asset.url`

   ```
   let asset = self.audioPlayerItem?.currentItem?.asset
   if asset == nil {
       return nil
   }
   if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
       return urlAsset.url.path
   }
   ```

**Edited**: if you use local file, init URL with         `URL.init(fileURLWithPath: )` instead of `URL.init(string: )`. If you use `URL.init(string: )`, string will be full path (contains `file:///`), not path.

2. That's ok, the decoding result is the same. Try to read reference [A html space is showing as %2520 instead of %20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084935/a-html-space-is-showing-as-2520-instead-of-20)

P/S: that snippet is just pseudo, please follow the idea from that snippet.

Comment: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: ) returns file:///Users.....   URL.init(string: ) returns /Users/.. and cuts off at the application part as posted in question... i am perplexed.

Comment: is the file:// the problem?  it seems common enough.  i just know that file manager cant find files with it.  so why is it there? to what end?