# Is there a Google Chrome switch (command line) to toggle url-encoding?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have written a C# code that calls Google Chrome to load a specific url on the computers local hard drive. The C# code already encodes the URL (replaces space characters with %20) and this used to work fine until a couple of weeks ago that [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084935/a-html-space-is-showing-as-2520-instead-of-20) started happening!

The quickest band-aid seems to be modifying the C# code to not replace " " with %20. But the Chrome behavior may change in the future or some customers may not have the same version/settings of the chrome installed.

I think the sustainable solution is to Tell Chrome to either Encode or not encode the URL. Now my question is:

**Is there a Chrome switch that enforces it to either translate the url or ignore it?**

**Does it have a setting or option for this?**

I have found a couple of lists with Chrome Switches [Here](http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html) and [Here](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/06/list-useful-google-chrome-command-line-switches/). However both of these lists are incomplete and refer to [this reference](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). I have Ctrl+F'ed for "URL" and "URI" but did not come across a relevant answer.

Thanks in advance.

---

I have already asked this question on Super User, however I think
people in this forum has more expertise on solving these types of
issues. (Also after 24hrs, the question in Super User has not received
*any* feedback at all!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Switch for it, however, as HexBolt has stated adding the "file://" tells Chrome that the url is already translated. Please see his extension to the [answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084935/a-html-space-is-showing-as-2520-instead-of-20?noredirect=1&lq=1).