# Percent encoded URLs not found

Tags: html

I am generating a webpage.  The generator takes a page title given as a string and converts it to a .html filename.  For example, if the title is `first`, the filename is `first.html`.

I understand that a URL path segment can only contain certain characters and that all others [need to be percent encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669692/valid-characters-for-directory-part-of-a-url-for-short-links#4669755).  A title of `second post` should therefore be given filename `second%20post.html`.

The trouble is that pages with filenames which are percent encoded are not loaded; `second%20post.html` is 404.  Non-percent encoded filenames work fine; `first.html`, `second+post.html`, and `second post.html` (with a space) *will* load.

When `second post.html` is loaded, the address bar shows:

`http://localhost:8000/second%20post.html`

When `second%20post.html` is loaded, the address bar also shows:

`http://localhost:8000/second%20post.html`

yet gives a 404.

Why does `second%20post.html` not load whereas `second post.html` does?  Could it be related to how the files are stored on disk?

### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel='shortcut icon' type="image/png" href="static/favicon.png" />
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <ul>
                <li><p class="post-title"><a href="./first.html">first</a></p></li>
                <li><p class="post-title"><a href="./second post.html">second post</a></p></li>
                <li><p class="post-title"><a href="./second%post.html">second post</a></p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### first.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel='shortcut icon' type="image/png" href="static/favicon.png" />
        <title>First post</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <p>First post<p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### 'second post.html'

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel='shortcut icon' type="image/png" href="static/favicon.png" />
        <title>Second post</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Second post, with a space<p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### second%20post.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel='shortcut icon' type="image/png" href="static/favicon.png" />
        <title>Second post</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Second post, percent encoded<p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: White spaces in the URL are replaced by `%20` thats a normal behavior.

Comment: You have a typo in a third link, `second%post` instead of `second%20post`, that's why you have 404. And doctype should be just `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: @artanik, yes that was it.  *sigh*  Thank you.  Should I delete this question or would it be appropriate for you to answer and me accept?

Comment: @LoremIpsum, I've decided to answer because it might be helpful for others 

Comment: fwiw, i'm still having issues with the actual generator.  I'll guess I just need to strip it down completely so that it produces precisely what's asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in a third link, `second%post` instead of `second%20post`, that's why you have 404.

Anyway, if you want to open the exact `second%20post.html` file, the link should be `second%2520post.html`, according to the [URL encoding method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: Thank you, again.  The issue in my real project was double encoding.  The fix seems to be simply removing the encoding step and letting browsers deal with it.  Or forcing a limited character set.  Double encoding is described in more detail here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16085190/5065796